# Designing message handler

Tags: design, c#, design-patterns

I am writing an application that receives different kinds of messages from an external device. The messages are of different types and they are received from the device in the form of a string.

For each message type, there exists a DTO object representing the parsed message, and a parser class which parses the string message into the DTO.

I would like to implement a `MessageHandler` class which receives messages, parses the messages by using the correct parser, and provides a means for the client to provide handlers for the different kinds of messages.

I have come up with the following design:

```
internal class MessageHandler
{
    public event EventHandler<MessageTypeAEventArgs>? MessageAReceived;
    public event EventHandler<MessageTypeBEventArgs>? MessageBReceived;

    public void HandleMessage(string message)
    {
        MessageType type = GetMessageType(message);
        switch (type)
        {
            case MessageType.A:
                MessageA messageA = _typeAMessageParser.Parse(message);
                MessageAReceived?.Invoke(this, messageA);
                break;
            case MessageType.B:
                MessageB messageB = _typeBMessageParser.Parse(message);
                MessageBReceived?.Invoke(this, messageB);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

When a message is received, the client invokes `HandleMessage` to pass the string message to the `MessageHandler`. The client can provide handlers by subscribing to the different kinds of events.

I am not convinced that this is a good design. I am looking for suggestions or design patterns which could help me improve it.

Comment: Improve *how*? What do *you* think is problematic with the code?   What are you trying to optimize for?

Comment: I don't know if this would be an improvement in your case, but if all the message event arg types had a common base type of `MessageTypeEventArgs`, only one single `MessageReceived` event would be required and consumers could switch on the message type. Note that the case statement and the case expressions can switch on pattern matching expressions like type patterns: `switch (eventArgs) { case MessageTypeAEventArgs a: ...`

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR

Comment: Since this is working code, I think this question belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632)